# Writing to JSON file using ajax and php. Server not recieving POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I tried following the steps in a few other stackoverflow questions, but for some reason my server is not showing any indicator of recieving a request. I know that the client is sending the request since it shows up in firefox debugger.
Here is the js method:

```
function writeToFile(dat) {
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'dataSaveAjax.php',
        method  : 'post',
        data    : { 'data': JSON.stringify(dat) },
        success : function( response ) {
            alert( response);
          }
    });
}
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen('general.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($_POST['data']));
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: what are you expecting to see as a response? you are not sending any response back to the client

Comment: You are encode your data double: `JSON.stringify(dat)` and `json_encode($_POST['data'])`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Sorry, I meant that my json file remains blank. It does not get updated.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['data']))` to see if you're actually receiving something.

Comment: Does your PHP process have sufficient rights to write to that file?

Comment: @AbdulSadikYalcin Hmm, I get `XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://127.0.0.1:5500/dataSaveAjax.php
\nLine Number 1, Column 1:`. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your code like that

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('general.json', 'w');
$writtingResponse = fwrite($fp, $_POST['data']);
fclose($fp);
echo $writtingResponse;

?>
```

You did not write any response and you encode json twice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I noticed that it is encoded twice, my bad. But the main issue here is that the general.json file remains blank. Any reason as to why that could be?

Comment: I've tried that php code and it works, did you check your ajax request on Dev tools ?

Comment: Sorry, but I am a beginner. How would I go about doing that? I saw a post request being sent using the networks tab in the inspect element in firefox. Also, it had code 405, if that helps.

Comment: 405 means method not allowed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405 can you access your post url on browser by typing it like sitename.com/phpfile.php ?

Comment: I guess your problem it you put header function in your php code that says it's xml, would you provide dataSaveAjax.php file

Comment: Umm, php header? The php code in the question is the php file in its entireity. Is there anything more that is to be added? Also, when I go http://127.0.0.1:5500/dataSaveAjax.php, the php file is downloaded. Is that normal behaviour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181082/discussion-between-noblesiks-and-muhittincokelek).

Answer (score 0):

first you need to understand what is the reason and why our script does not work. First, let's look at the server part (php). First, put the data in a variable, instead of $ _POST ['data'] try to do something like:

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen('general.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, 'MyTest');
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

If this does not work, most likely the reason is that you need to set the write permissions for the file ([Chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)).

If everything is recorded correctly, then something is wrong with the client part of your site. When it comes to POST / GET queries, I usually use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). It allows not only to test requests, but also to generate code. If you run a query through Postman and the result is written to a file, then the error is unambiguous in javascript. Try to press F12 in the browser and go to the js console, there you will see an error message. Do you use jQuery in the example, and is it connected? Is it connected before you try to execute the script?
Try to look at the data that you are trying to send using console (F12)

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(dat));
```

Are your data really going to be collected, or are you trying to send empty data to the file?